# Accessing mounted share from command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, samba

I am able to mount a Samba share in Ubuntu's graphical desktop with "connect to server". This allows me to use that share with desktop applications.

I'd also like to access the share from the command line, but haven't seen a  corresponding entry reported by `mount`.

How can I (mount and) access the Samba share from the command line?

Comment: Nothing showing up in `/mnt`? Or where are the files, according to the file explorer?

Comment: @xenoid It says that files are at `sftp://myaccount@myserver/mypath".

Comment: Then you aren't accessing them via Samba, but using SFTP, which AFAIK has nothing to do with Samba but everything to do with SSH. So, see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33480/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-samba-location-ive-mounted-in-nautilus-on-the-command-li) (btw, for Ubuntu questions, AskUbuntu is a better SE site that SuperUser)

Comment: @xenoid Many thanks for those links. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files show as `sftp://myaccount@myserver/mypath` in the explorer, then you aren't accessing them via Samba, but using SFTP, which AFAIK has nothing to do with Samba but everything to do with SSH.

When your Samba share is [adequately mounted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently), the files should appear somewhere under your [`/run` directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33480/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-samba-location-ive-mounted-in-nautilus-on-the-command-li).

Btw, for Ubuntu questions, [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is a better SE site than SuperUser.